# Permutations Combinations Calculation and listing them

Tags: math, language-agnostic, permutation, combinations, pseudocode

Hi don't know much about pseudocodes so I would like to ask how to do something I want to. I want to print the list of all the possible combinations of the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. 
I need a code printing the combinations of 8 digits BUT I always want to have 69 before these combinations.
I don't want to knwo how many the combinaitons are, I want the code to print the list of them.

ie. 6900000000
    6900000001
    6900000002
    .
    .
    .
    6999999999
but the one under the other not next to it. I need them in a list.
I really hope you could help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read your lecture notes and try doing at least some work by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution will to print all numbers in range `[0,10^8)`, and just add the 69 as a prefix. (make sure not to forget the leading zeros)

The pseudo code should be:

```
for (integer i = 0; i < 10^8; i++) {
   print 69
   print i (with leading zeros)
   print EOL (End of Line)
}
```

Comment: Note to the OP: Careful using the literal `10^8` as your upper bound in your programming language of choice. Most languages interpret this as logical XOR. `10 XOR 8 = 2`, which is not `100,000,000`.

Comment: @SliverBell: Not directly, but a similar code can. Have a look on [this sample](http://ideone.com/7FG04C). Note it fails in ideone, I assume because it has way too much output and the framework restricted it, should work on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for i = 1 to i = XXXX {
  print(69 + $i);
}
```

Comment: thank you, can I run it online somewhere? or can you suggest a software to run the code?